# Get a list of index of each item in a list as if it's sorted

Tags: sort

I'd like to know which item of my list would appear in which place by index, if the list was sorted.

If I had a list like this

```
342
10
403
111
365
4
102
```

I'd like to get a list that shows what the index of each items would be like if the list was sorted, like this.

```
5
2
7
4
6
1
3
```

How can I do this in Terminal?

Comment: How 111 is interpreted to 2...? What is the logic? If next item of the list are 365 , 4 , and 102 what will be the expected index?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou  I'm not sure if the term I'm using is correct. What I want to know is what the order of each numbers would be like when the list is sorted in ascending order. That's why the index of 10 in the first list is changed to 1 in the second list. 10 is the smallest number in the first list.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I looked up the [options of sort command](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/sort.htm) but it didn't seem to have the option to do this? I assume there's already some command or option to achieve this? Isn't this a common task? I just don't know what it's technically called....

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what the real-world application for this is little puzzle, but I was surprised to find a cute little solution that involves running the list through one command, then another command, then the first command again, then the second command again... :)

```
cat -n | sort -nk +2 | cat -n | sort -nk +2 | cut -f1
```

Comment: Very nice solution!